# Packagemaker to build installer on Mac

Tags: macos, installation, packagemaker

I am a Mac newbie. I need to create a installer for Mac 10.8. I did some research and it seems it can be built by packagemaker. I built .pkg using packagemaker.  I have few questions

1.When I inspect what's inside it, it's different from other installer I download from the internet such as from http://www.bittorrent.com/downloads/mac. When I show the contents of other installer, they all have a content folder and has a hierarch inside the content folder, which mine doesn't. Does the installer create these folder automatically or I need to create these folders and put files inside?
2. When I run my installer, it has default look, that on the left side of the window, it have introduction, if I click on "Continue", it move the "select destination". How can I build some thing same as bittorrent which doesn't have these pages? Is there a step by step guide? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found that Xcode create Application bundle, it creates the hierarchical content folder. So packagemaker is not the right tool to use.